# Javascript find all "\" and replace with "/"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck doing this. I am working with a CMS built in ASP.net and it generates image sources using `\` for folder path. I need to read this src and use it somewhere else as a background image to a div, which requires `/` for path separators.

Tried these without success:

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\', 'g'), '/');
str.replace(/\/g), '/');
```

Thanks

Comment: simply change like this: str.replace(/\\/g), '/');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```js
 var str = "assets\imges\img.jpg";
 var res = str.replace(/\\/g, "/");
```

Answer (score 5):

`\` is the escape character in string and regular expression literals. To produce a literal `\` you have to escape it itself:

```js
console.log(
  "\\path\\to\\file".replace(/\\/g, '/')
  //                          ^^
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach I suppose.

```js
let str = `\\test\\string\\h.html`;
console.log(str);

str = str.split('\\').join('/');
console.log(str);
```